# SQL Query Join Limit Results to One Item Per ID

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

So I have 2 tables ... Products and Images

```
Products 
---------
id
value1
value2
value3
etc..

Images
---------
id
productId
imageName
```

The image table will have more than one image per product,  so when I run this query:
(the != 0 is because some images don't have a productId so I want to exclude them,  not sure if there is a better way to handle that, or if I even need to include that)

```
select p.*, i.imageName 
from products p, images i 
where p.id = i.productId and i.productId != 0
```

I get the results, but it gives me multiple entries and I just want one result per product and i want it to pull up THE IMAGE THAT WAS ADDED FIRST  (so the oldest one) ...

Currently the results look like this ---

```
id : 1
imagename: name1.jpg

id : 2
imagename: name5.jpg

id: 2
imagename: name6.jpg

id: 2
imagename: name7.jpg

id: 3
imagename:  name3.jpg

etc... etc...
```

I want it to look like this ...

```
id: 1
imagename: name1.jpg

id: 2
imagename: name5.jpg

id: 3
imagename: name 3.jpg
```

Does this makes sense?  Can anyone help me figure out my problem?

Comment: what criteria do you use to select name5.jpg but not name6.jpg? Is it just a random pick or you have something explicit?

Comment: I would guess that `select distinct` might work?

Comment: Oldest file chronologically,  all images have a timestamp on them, so i would probably sort by timestamp, but i think the database retrieves chrono anyway, so prob not necessary to include timestamp logic in the query

Comment: I added the `greatest-n-per-group` tag.  Follow that tag for dozens of answers in SQL for this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this would work, although you will have to check it for typos.

```
SELECT p.*,
       (SELECT i.imageName
          FROM images
         WHERE i.productId = p.id
        ORDER BY i.date_created ASC
         LIMIT 1)
          AS imageName
  FROM products p
```

Comment: Just a comment. Oldest file chronologically implies `ORDER BY i.date_created ASC`. It is'nt?

Comment: @danihp - dates.  bah.  Thanks for the pointer, you were right.

Answer (score 4):

Adding "group by p.id" at the end of your query should do the work, but now you don't know what image you get.

bye

Gianluca

Comment: This actually works for what I want,  but I am going with the one above that incorporates the subselect just because it guarantees i get the right one.    Great attempt though, earned you an upvote from me.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a column in the image table that stores the date and time each image was added.  Then you should be able to do this (I hope, dunno if MySQL allows it):

```
select p.*, i.imageName 
  from products p, images i 
 where p.id = i.productId 
   and i.productId != 0 
   and i.addedDate = (select min(i2.addedDate)
                        from images i2
                       where i2.productId = p.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the images.id as my method to determine the oldest. You could use a date or datetime field, but if more than one image was added for that productid at the same time, you will get multiple records unless the query is further modified to account for that possibility. I'm guessing image.id is unique, and so wont have that problem

```
select p.id
     , im.imageName
  from products p
left
  join ( select id
              , theDate
              , imageName
           from images
           join (select min(id) minId
                         from images
                      group 
                          by productId) oldestImages
             on oldestImages.minId = images.id
  ) im
  on im.productId = p.id
```